# detect move event by index pointer in android

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am working on a multitouch program that needs to record only the movements made by the second finger or index pointer. 
Now the documentation says that we can use MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK and & it with action and shift by INDEX_SHIFT to get the pointer that made the action like going up or down. But this technique does not work on move.

Is there anyway that we can detect the move action made by a certain pointer alone?

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can have something like this in your `View` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(event.getPointerCount()>1){
                //where 1 is the index of the second finger
                final int Y = event.getY(1); 
                final int X = event.getX(1); 
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

so depending on what finger you want to get the movent you can set the get to that index. Rember that values may be from 0 (the first pointer that is down) to `getPointerCount()-1`.
I tested this on 2.2 Gingerbread so I hope it be useful for you :)

Comment: I am using a similar solution, but I still need to use the ID to find the index. The user could have lifted the first finger and put it down again and try to move, which according to Android, would be a move by pointer with index 1. I believe the ID would be different though.

Comment: if the user lift a finger then you can dinamically change the id of the finger you will be registering in your MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effective pointer index by checking which pointer changed:

```
private final int MAX_POINTER = 5; // 5 different touch pointers supported on most devices
private float mLastTouchPositionX[];
private float mLastTouchPositionY[];

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent aEvent)
int tActionIndex = aEvent.getActionIndex();
int tPointerCount = aEvent.getPointerCount();
    /*
     * Check which pointer changed on move
     */
    if (tMaskedAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tPointerCount && i < MAX_POINTER; i++) {
            if (mLastTouchPositionX[i] != aEvent.getX(i) || mLastTouchPositionY[i] != aEvent.getY(i)) {
                mLastTouchPositionX[i] = aEvent.getX(i);
                mLastTouchPositionY[i] = aEvent.getY(i);
                // Found new action index
                tActionIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```